# Get the position of a row after sorting mysqli result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking for a way to get the place of a specific item after sorting my mysqliresult. I have a table like this:

```
id_______|_Name_____________|_ParentID
58       | Carl             | 15
55       | Clark            | 15
12       | David            | 4
23       | Sophie           | 15
45       | Amanda           | 15
```

I am only interested in the rows with ParentID 15 and I want to sort them by their Name. Then I want to look at a specific item, say id 55 (Clark) and know which row number it is placed on. I want to generate a table like this:

```
id_______|_Name_____________|_ParentID
45       | Amanda           | 15
58       | Carl             | 15
55       | Clark            | 15
23       | Sophie           | 15
```

I then want to get the number 3 when I am interested in Clark, since his row is the third row in this new table.

Is this at all possible to do with mysqli? If it can't be done in a single statement, I have to loop through all selected items and have a count that increases for every item until I find my correct one but I would really like to avoid this since the number of items to loop through quickly increases.

Comment: Just you need to find "Clark" position or you also need parentID =15 and name sort order query also?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable s
        WHERE t.parent_id = s.parent_id 
           and t.name <= s.name) as Cnt
FROM YourTable t
```

Output :

```
id_______|_Name_____________|_ParentID__|_Cnt
58       | Carl             | 15        |  2
55       | Clark            | 15        |  3
12       | David            | 4         |  1
23       | Sophie           | 15        |  4
45       | Amanda           | 15        |  1
```

Now `Cnt` column contain the row position, so to get any one of their positions:

```
SELECT tt.cnt 
FROM (...above query here...) tt
WHERE tt.name = ? --optional
  AND tt.parent_id = ? --optional
```

Comment: user want only parentID 15 records as output.

Comment: And? I gave him a dynamic answer to work with every parentID, thats seems an odd request to just query one parentID @RuchishParikh

Comment: Checked.  Working fine. :)

Comment: Question - for how long will I be able to use this column? Will it ever disapear? @sagi

Comment: What do you mean? You will be able to use it as long as you keep it, you can always store this in a table and you will for ever have this.

Comment: That's what I was wondering, I can use this column until i colse my connection to the server but if I connect again - it won't be there.

Comment: @e.klara.k Ok, I don't understand the question.. Just select it again or store it somewhere

Comment: I understand now so it's fine! Thank you!

Comment: Great , no problem, I'll appreciate an approval then @e.klara.k

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row for `Clark` by doing:

```
select count(*)
from t
where t.ParentId = 15 and
      t.Name <= 'Clark';
```

Indexes `t(Name, ParentId)` will speed performance.

Comment: How do you mean @sagi?

Comment: I mean if you want to get both `Clark` and `Carl` position, you will have to execute this query twice.

Comment: @sagi . . . The question only mentions `'Clark'`.

Comment: No.. He gave an example, he only mention parentid 15.

Answer (score 0):

In [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) you can use [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

```
SELECT T.*,  if(@a, @a:=@a+1, @a:=1) as rownum 
FROM T
WHERE ParentID=15
ORDER BY Name
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20052/2)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE parent_id = 15 ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Comment: No, He says he wants to get a table like that, after that he can get whichever one he likes from the result set, because the result is sorted.